# Django - i want to view this plot into Browser

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django for now i can pass variables but i don't know how to render dynamic plots

---

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from random import randrange

x_data, y_data = [], []

figure = pyplot.figure()
line, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y_data, '-')

def update(frame):
    x_data.append(datetime.now())
    y_data.append(randrange(0, 100))
    line.set_data(x_data, y_data)
    figure.gca().relim()
    figure.gca().autoscale_view()
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=200)

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Django here ? Have you an idea of your Model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph rendered through pyplot (python) will not be dynamic in the browser. You can use any javascript chart library which is dynamic and provide the data from Django (by using REST API, Ajax, or simple request).